# How to map values to a factor in R?

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data set in R with countries. I need to make a factor that maps **1** when US appears, and **0** to the rest of the countries. How can I do that? I have tried `mapvalues()` but I can't find a way to put all the countries in the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below

```
Data$Category[Data$Country == 'US'] = 1       
Data$Category[Data$Country != 'US' ] = 0
```

And then convert the Category column to factor, something like this

```
Data$Category = factor(Data$Category,
                    levels=c(0,1))
```

I hope this works

Comment: @sindri_baldur sure thanks. I will keep that in mind.